# Django boto3 with s3 not working in production

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, large-files

So I am currently trying to enable large file uploads for my site [www.theraplounge.co/](http://www.theraplounge.co/) the only problem is I’m using boto3 to upload directly to s3 with https://justdjango.com/blog/how-to-upload-large-files as a guide. The good thing is large files get uploaded when I’m on development server. When I launch code to production server on heroku large files don’t upload anymore. I don’t think code would work locally but not in production which leads me to think the problem may be heroku 30s timeouts although I’m not sure. Anyone got a glue or a hint at what’s going on?

Comment: Assuming that your client is uploading to your Django server and from there to S3, then don't do that. Instead, share a signed S3 URL from server to client and have the client upload directly to S3.  More [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout).

Comment: @jarmod Actually I ended up using Javascript AWS SDK to upload the video plus some of my own work arounds to create a two step process that uploads large files. Give it a try and create a account on my site. www.theraplounge.co/ I manually set the max file size to 500MB but it could go bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I ended up using Javascript AWS SDK to upload the video plus some of my own work arounds to create a two step process that uploads large files. Give it a try and create a account on my site. [www.theraplounge.co/](http://www.theraplounge.co/) I manually set the max file size to 500MB but it could go bigger.

Comment: I think you're saying that you added the AWS SDK to your client in the browser, yes? If so, then the in-browser SDK needs AWS credentials which your server is presumably sending to the client so be aware that those are visible to your user which can be a security concern.

Comment: @jarmod I read that sharing your CognitoIdentity in the browser is complete ok here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837246/is-it-safe-to-show-the-aws-cognito-pool-id-in-my-html

Comment: OK, wasn't aware that you were using Cognito. You might also want to take a look at [Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) just to familiarize yourself with its capabilities for future developments.

Comment: @jarmod  lol you really got me cracking up. No thanks not into web builders

Comment: What's a 'web builder'? If you're referring to tools for building static websites, that's not what Amplify's about.

Comment: @jarmod guess I have to learn more about it